# Can the Lebesgue integral $\int _U f(x)\,dx$ in $\mathbb {R}^d$ exist if $\int _W f|_W \,dS$ doesn't exist?

Tags: submanifold

Let $M \subset \mathbb {R}^d$ be a $n$-dimensional submanifold, $W$ is a  coordinate chart of $M$ with the map $\varphi : U \to V$ and $f \colon U \to \mathbb {R}$ is a continuous function function.

Can the Lebesgue integral $\int _U f(x)\,dx$ in $\mathbb {R}^d$ exist if $\int _W f|_W \,dS$ doesn't exist?

Comment: wild guess, map area = coordinate chart...?

Comment: I just looked up the definition and that makes a lot of sense, thanks!